# Metabox on a custom page - How to include the appropriate default scripts and styles?

Tags: metabox, wp-enqueue-script, add-submenu-page

I have created a metabox on a CPT's submenu page created using `add_meta_box`. I see the metabox's style is not similar to the other metaboxes available on post edit pages. Moreover, the accordion type control doesn't work here. When I had added the same metabox on a post edit page, everything worked as expected. I'm sure I need to enqueue default styles and scripts this custom page. How do I do it?

Update:
This is how I have created my metabox:

```
add_action("load-troll-cpt_page_show-trollers", "troll_add_metaboxes");
function troll_add_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box("troll-metabox", "Troll Meta", "display_troll_metabox", "troll-menu-page", "normal", "core");
}

function display_my_metabox() {
    echo "This is the metabox content";
}
```

Here is how the metabox looks like:

[image]

Comment: How did you create the metabox? Post your code please.

Comment: Okay, I will edit my answer.